# xcode: calculate expression when Debug

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

Can Xcode calculate the value of an expression while debugging?

I mean like MS visual studio, there is a "watch" window, where the debugger can input expressions composed with the local variables, and vs will calculate the value. can similar thing be done also in xcode? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Run/Show/Expressions window. You can also use the `print` (or `p`) command in the console window (the one with the `(gdb)` prompt).

Comment: Thank you! but could you tell me how can I see the value of the expression, not something like  {(unichar *)Xcode_CFStringSummary($VAR, $ID)}:s